# Как вставит строку внутрь другой строки при нахождении определенного символа

Tags: c++, строки

Есть символ С и строки S1, S2. Перед каждым входжением символа С в строку S1 нужно вставить строку S2.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это можно сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "one two three" );
    std::string t( "," );
    char c = ' ';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find( c, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          pos += t.size() + sizeof( c ) )
    {
        s.insert( pos, t );
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
one two three
one, two, three
```

Можно предварительно подсчитать, сколько в строке встречается символ в `c`, чтобы заранее зарезервировать память в строке `s`, а затем выполнить указанный в программе цикл.

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "one two three" );
    std::string t( "," );
    char c = ' ';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    auto n = std::count( s.begin(), s.end(), c );

    s.reserve( s.size() + n * t.size() );

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find( c, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          pos += t.size() + sizeof( c ) )
    {
        s.insert( pos, t );
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```